# How to join and generate table searching by name

Tags: mysql, database

I have 3 tables (product, company, purchaseHistory).

```
product has (product_id(PK), product_name)
company has (company_id(PK), company)name)
purchaseHistory has(purchaseHistory_id, company_id(FK), product_id(FK), purchase_amount)
```

What I want to do is to search with product_name(like search) and company_name (like_search) and get every list of purchaseHistory.

Becuase purchaseHistory only have id not name I can't like search and get the lists. I found clue that I can do it with join but I am not use to it. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use LEFT JOIN

`SELECT * FROM purchaseHistory 
LEFT JOIN product ON purchaseHistory.product_id=product.product_id
LEFT JOIN company ON purchaseHistory.company_id=company.company_id
WHERE product_name LIKE '%KEYWORD%' OR company_name LIKE '%KEYWORD%'`